# lands vanish without reason

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I`m making a globe, that can be rotated. And I need to drag countries and lands together (yes, I know, that I can use only countries, but I need both). But if I do it like that, lands vanishes, and I have no idea what's wrong.  But if I comment "Countries!", this code works perfectly. 
It's first time working with this, maybe I have a mistake with topojson?

```
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
svg.append("path").datum(graticule).attr("class", "graticule").attr("d", path);

//Land
d3.json("https://rawgit.com/jonataswalker/map-utils/master/data/json/world-110m.json", function(error, topo) {
  if (error) throw error;    
  var land = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.land);
      svg.selectAll("path.foreground").data([land]).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).attr("class", "foreground");
});

//Countries!
d3.json("https://rawgit.com/Bramsiss/Globe/master/world-counries.json", function(collection) {
var countries = svg.selectAll("path").data(collection.features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).attr("class", "country");  
});

//drag
var λ = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, width]).range([-180, 180]);
var φ = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, height]).range([90, -90]);    
    var drag = d3.drag().subject(function() {
        var r = projection.rotate();
        return {
      x: λ.invert(r[0]),
      y: φ.invert(r[1])
    };
  }).on("drag", function() {
    projection.rotate([λ(d3.event.x), φ(d3.event.y)]);
    svg.selectAll(".foreground").attr("d", path);    
  });  
  svg.call(drag);
```

Comment: Could you please create a JSFiddle / working code snippet.

Comment: https://codepen.io/bramsis/pen/vWazzv  this is whitout countries

Comment: https://codepen.io/bramsis/pen/xPJayW   and this is whith them

Comment: @NanduKalidindi A jsfiddle is unacceptable unless he includes a complete working example here. [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue arises here:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
   .data(collection.features)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("d", path)
   .attr("class", "country");  
  });
```

svg.selectAll("path") selects one existing path - the world's outline. Your enter selection therefore does not include the first path - it has already been appended. It is part of the update selection. You do set the datum for the first path with this code, but you do not update its shape.

*If you look very carefully, Angola has lighter boundaries than the neightbours, this is because instead of two lines (the edges of two countries), the border consists of one line.*

Since you only use the enter to create and shape the new elements, the original outline of the earth's land is unchanged. However, when you use the update selection to rotate the earth:

```
svg.selectAll(".foreground, .country").attr("d", path);
```

you update the shape of all the paths based on the data appended when you added the countries. Since you replaced the data bound to the first path in the DOM (the outline of the earth's land) with the data for the first item in your countries data array, the path is redrawn according to the new data.

*This is why if you drag the earth, the border of Angola changes, if you look at the DOM, you'll also note that this country has the class "foreground", rather than "country".*

Solution:

Use a null selection to append countries:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
```

or

```
svg.selectAll()
```

or

```
svg.selectAll(".country")  // since there are no elements with this class yet.
```

Here's an [updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOBYRK).